# Obtain the last Inserted record of a group of same ID's

Tags: mysql

So, i have this structure:

```
IDSale    DateInserted  
1          2011-1-12
1          2011-1-13
1          2011-1-10
2          2011-1-12
2          2011-1-15
2          2011-1-11
```

The result of my question would be:

```
IDSale    DateInserted  
1          2011-1-13
2          2011-1-15
```

How can I achieve this in a MYSQL Query. I can do this programatically, but

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for **this particular case**, the following will do the trick:

```
SELECT IDSale, MAX(DateInserted) DateInserted
FROM tablename
GROUP BY IDSale
```

Comment: Ah, yes! could you believe i forgot the obvious!, thank you very much!